# Unable to set divider colour in table layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

My table layout is as shown below, I used the below code to set the dividers between the rows and their colours, I can see in my design that the dividers were set but not the divider colour!

**Please advice how I can set the divider colour between rows?**

Code to set dividers in the table layout and their colours.

```
 android:showDividers="middle"
 android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
```

Full Table Layout code.

```
        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/table_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
            tools:context=".BookAppointment"
            android:stretchColumns="1">


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/table_row_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding"
                    android:src="@drawable/india_flag" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cell_text_size" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevron_right_24px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            </TableRow>



            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/table_row_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cell_text_size" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/chevron_right_24px"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
            </TableRow>




        </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem in your code. But here is an exact example.

**For dividers between rows :**

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:showDividers="middle">
```

**and for dividers between columns:**

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:showDividers="middle">
```

**Explaination:**

The divider tag in `<TableLayout>` is used to place divider between it's direct childrens i.e **Rows**.

While the divider tag in `<TableRow>` is used to place divider between it's direct childrens i.e **Columns**

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a drawable 'cell_divider.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="#f00" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Than you can set the drawable in divider property like:

```
android:divider="@drawable/cell_divider"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using drawable shape as divider for table layout.

**divider_shape.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:insetBottom="2dp"
 android:insetTop="2dp">
 <shape>
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFCCCCCC" />
 </shape>
 </inset>
```

and add it to your table layout as below

```
android:divider="@drawable/divider_shape"
android:showDividers="middle"
```